# cannot find my Roblox game published in private mode

Tags: game-development, roblox

Published my first Roblox game in private mode just to try it on a tablet, but there's no way i can find it. "Private" mode states it is accessible only by developer. I'm the developer, i'm using the same account, but still have no idea how to find and test my game.

Any help or better doc reference would be really appreciated.

Comment: I think you'll need to ask Roblox directly for help. So you can see the game in your developer account, just not to choose inside the game?

Answer (score 1):

Try navigating to the inventory tab. There you should be able to select a category and try and select places.
Then if necessary change the subcategory section to created by me and it should come up with a list of places created by you.
Including private ones.

This is a PC picture of what I mean on tablet it will likely look very different but I know you can find it in the same place.
*If you look to the left of the picture you can see the "places" option*
[image]

Comment: Yes it is not user friendly at all, but it works. Private games are showing up under More > Profile > View Full Profile > Inventory (in Collections) > Places (and make sure to scroll up as it may not show all games otherwise).